# Firebase Facebook Login on Android Won't Work

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

My code is broken somewhere and I can't find the error.. Please help ....

---------------- build.gradle 1 ------------------

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.facelog.fire"
    minSdkVersion 16
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
}
}
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.8.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

------------------- build.gradle 2 ---------------

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}
}
    allprojects {
    repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

--------------- manifest ------------------

```
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
```

---------------------- xml ---------------------

```
 <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
            android:id="@+id/login_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked firebase console /authentication/providers whether facebook is enable or not. For more details check the firebase docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/facebook-login

Comment: Yes,Firebaes and facebook developer settings, app id, secret, hash code,,,, all of them ok. I think error in manifest or build.gradle.